# Cardinality of a set of sets with an infinite element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm taking an introductory course to discrete mathematics in which I was given the following informal definition for a finite set: **a finite set is a set which one could in principle count and finish counting.** taking this intuition:

If $S$ is a set of sets and we define it as the following: $S = \{4,\{4\} ,\{4,\{4\}\},\{N\}\}$ What is the $|S|$?

My professor solution is that $|S| = 4$ while my solution is $|S| = \infty$ since the subset {N} is uncountable. Which one of us is correct? Also, would it make any difference if we change the definition of $S$ to be the following:

$S = \{4,\{4\} ,\{4,\{4\}\},N\}$

Comment: In the original S, the "last" three elements are all sets. In the new S, the "last" element is *still* (just) a set

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you want the set of naturals, you can use \Bbb N to get $\Bbb N$.  The Bbb stands for blackboard bold.  Instead of changing the definition of $S$ it would be better to assign a new letter, so make the last set $T$ to avoid confusion when somebody refers to them.

Comment: You are using the term "uncountable" incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your professor is right.  $\{\Bbb N\}$ is one element.  Nothing is said about how big that element is.  In your follow-up question, changing the definition of $S$ changes $S$, but the new one still has four elements.  We have $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, which is still one set, which is one element of the new $S$.